# Xcode is not recognising parse with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have followed this tutorial about using Parse with Swift in Xcode. (http://codewithchris.com/using-parse-swift-xcode-6/) I followed every step, including the imports and the bridge between objective c in the header class. But, when I try to type `parse` in Xcode, it does not suggest any functions, so clearly it is not recognising the parse libraries. How can this be fixed? I have been trying it many times and it is just not working.

Comment: Try deleting "Derived Data" for your project and restart Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a bug in xcode at the moment. Reload Xcode and try it again. This time, Xcode will recognise it and it will work!

Comment: I've had this problem before, and a restart of Xcode seemed to work as well

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have an error similar to this, I do the following:

1. Clean the project : Cmd + Shift + K
2. Clean the build folder : Cmd + Alt + Shift + K

If those don't work then I try :

3. Restart Xcode (as suggested above)
4. Delete the contents of the "Derived Data" folder:
   Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations

There you will find the location of the Derived Data Folder which you can delete.